# node-slack-sdk tutorial won't run with "TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, slack-api

It looks like the packages in the node slack API are somehow messed up, or following the instructions at https://slackapi.github.io/node-slack-sdk/getting_started, there is an error.

In running the given tutorial code:

```
const timeNotification = new IncomingWebhook(process.env.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL);
const currentTime = new Date().toTimeString();
timeNotification.send(`The current time is ${currentTime}`, (error, resp) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  console.log('Notification sent');
});
```

I get this exception:

```
slackbot/node_modules/@slack/client/dist/IncomingWebhook.js:26
        payload.text = message;
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined
    at IncomingWebhook.send (slackbot/node_modules/@slack/client/dist/IncomingWebhook.js:26:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (slackbot/slackbot.js:4:18)
```

Looking at the code involved, the definition of `IncomingWebhook` seems to have 2 arguments, the second of which defines the "defaults" variable, which in turn gets assigned to the "payload" variable.  It looks like the tutorial's definition of IncomingWebhook is wrong!  If I change the line to define an empty object like so:

```
IncomingWebhook(process.env.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, {});
```

I get another error further down the chain:

```
slackbot/node_modules/@slack/client/dist/IncomingWebhook.js:38
    util_1.callbackify(implementation)(callback);
           ^

TypeError: util_1.callbackify is not a function
    at IncomingWebhook.send (slackbot/node_modules/@slack/client/dist/IncomingWebhook.js:38:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (slackbot/slackbot.js:4:18)
```

In grepping around the dependencies, I do see a "callbackify" function on util here:

```
grep -RIi "function callbackify" * | grep js
node_modules/@slack/client/dist/util.js:    function callbackifyOnRejected(reason, cb) {
node_modules/@slack/client/dist/util.js:    function callbackify(original) {
```

Something seems very wrong with this default tutorial, or (hopefully), how I'm using it.  This is a new NPM init directory, using only the following dependencies (here's my package.json):

```
{
    "name": "slackbot",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "license": "Commerical",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@slack/client": "4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Here's my NPM/node verisons:

```
node --version
v6.13.1
npm --version
3.10.10
```

I'm running Linux Mint 18.1 Serena (based on Ubuntu Xenial) 4.8.0-39-generic kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I just had bad timing.  4.0.0 *just* got released, and had some bugs.  The second bug I mentioned is already fixed (though there's no new point version since the fix) by way of this issue: https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/492.  I have logged the 1st issue (needing a 2nd param to new IncomingWebhook) here, and it not fixed yet (just a documentation issue, will probably be resolved soon): https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/497